# is it possible to set title of fieldset element programatically?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html element fieldset with title(legend):

```
    <fieldset id="propertiesField" style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
                    <legend id="propertiesFieldTitle"></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Is it possible to set legend title programatically?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. What have you tried?

Comment: @j08691 $('#propertiesFieldTitle').val("title")

Comment: `.val()` is for form elements (e.g. input, textarea, select); use `.html()` or `.text()`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

   <fieldset id="propertiesField" style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
                    <legend id="propertiesFieldTitle"></legend>
</fieldset>
<script>
document.getElementById("propertiesFieldTitle").innerHTML = "legend";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```